# XCode 4 + SVN, source control is greyed out after checking out

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4

I have recently upgraded to XCode 4.0. I had an SVN repository setup working perfectly. After upgrading, it recognized my repository (in Organizer). I hit checkout, which it did. It created a new folder, inside of it a hidden .svn folder. All seems well, but when I right click any file and select 'Source control', all the options are greyed out.

It's as if the project is not linked up to the repository. I never had these issues in XCode 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all of the files locked, or does the working copy need to be cleaned?

Comment: Some stuff that was available in the source control menu moved to the  Version Editor (like blame, log). Maybe you were looking for these? It's under View --> Version Editor.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any change with the file. All the options are grey in 'Source control'.
Try to do some change to a file and see what happen.

You can also try File >> Source Control >> Commit... to see the svn works or not. This will commit the entire project.